# Realm - attempt to delete item x from section 0 which only contains 4 items before the update crash

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, realm, performbatchupdates

So I am using Realm with fine-grained notifications on my collectionview. When I select a cell, I keep getting the following error:

> attempt to delete item x from section 0 which only contains 4 items before the update

I've followed Realm's example code, and can't find what i'm doing wrong. My code is the following:

```
let producers: Results<Producer> = {
        ProducersRealm().getAllProducers()
    }()
    // receive notification
    var token: NotificationToken?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        registerViewCell()   
        token = producers.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in

            guard (self?.collectionView) != nil else { return }

            // MARK: - Switch on State

            switch changes {

            case .initial:
                self?.collectionView.reloadData()
                break
            case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
                self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    self?.collectionView.insertItems(at: insertions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))
                    self?.collectionView.deleteItems(at: deletions.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))
                    self?.collectionView.reloadItems(at: modifications.map({ IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}))

                }, completion: nil)
                break
            case .error(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                break
            }
        }
  }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return producers.count
}
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            realmProducer = producers[indexPath.row]

          favoriseItemRealm(realmProducer!, textAdded: "addedRetailer", textDeleted: "deletedRetailer", view: self, button: nil)
    }
```

So when a user presses on a cell, this will trigger the `favoriseItemRealm`, which will make sure a heart image appears or doesn't (works as it should on some cells, but gives back the above error on others, while I'm not deleting the cell).
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Code for favoriseItemRealm

```
  // if object is a Producer
if (object as? Producer) != nil {
    if let downcastObject = object as? Producer {
        let open = realm.objects(Producer.self).filter("id == %@", downcastObject.id).first
        try! realm.write {
            // user is offline
            if hasInternet() == false {
                if open!.favorite != true {
                    open?.favorite = true
                    if userLoggedIn() {
                        // write to dabatase if user is logged in, but offline
                        SyncFavoriteItemRealm.shared.saveOrUpdate((open?.id)!,favorite: true, type: ContentType.PRODUCER.rawValue)
                    }
                } else {
                    open?.favorite = false
                    if userLoggedIn() {
                        // write to dabatase if user is logged in, but offline
                        SyncFavoriteItemRealm.shared.saveOrUpdate((open?.id)!,favorite: false, type: ContentType.PRODUCER.rawValue)
                    }
                }
                // user is online
            } else {
                if open!.favorite != true {
                    open?.favorite = true
                    if userLoggedIn() {
                        //sync to backend
                    }
                    //GoogleAnalyticsHelper.shared.trackFavoriteItem(downcastObject)
                } else {
                    open?.favorite = false
                    if userLoggedIn() {
                        // sync to backend
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at producers.addNotificationBlock you are self?.collectionView.performBatchUpdates calling this method.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk yeah, i have an IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

Comment: You perform performBatchUpdates each time you update models from Realm. So each time collectionView is updated.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk yes, I want to update my model every time the user presses the button (my Realm database 'favorite' parameter in the Producer object is updated). Is this incorrect to do so?

Comment: Can you please post what the contents of `favoriseItemRealm` look like? If you're only updating the properties of the `Producer` objects, there should never be any items in the `deletion` object.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not sure what's going on, sorry. If you'd like, feel free to send a copy of your code to `help@realm.io` and we can try debugging it directly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got a bug like this thats why:

I got a viewController **A** with posts. Posts is a Results with Post realm entity. When tap on tableView's cell it leads to a viewController **B** where only one post shows. The token in **A** still works. If i delete post from **B** it leads to fire a token **A** with changes. I decided to debug and crash was at line `self.collectionV.reloadData()`. If i comment this line, than i see that when post is deleted in **B** and it pops to **A** there is an empty Item in UICollectionView where was this post.

There is a realm notification:

```
realmToken = posts?.observe() { [unowned self] changes in
            switch changes {
            case .initial(_):
                self.collectionV.reloadData()
                break
            case let .update(_, deletions, insertions, modifications):
                self.collectionV.performBatchUpdates({
                    self.collectionV.reloadItems(at: modifications.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
                    self.collectionV.insertItems(at: insertions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
                    self.collectionV.deleteItems(at: deletions.map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) })
                }, completion: { (completed: Bool) in
CRASH >>>           self.collectionV.reloadData()
                })
                break
            case let .error(error):
                self.show(error: error)
                break
            }
            self.stopLoading()
        }
```

I think that it could be because of UICollectionView internal behaviour, but maybe somebody make this clear?